# How to highlight items in scatter plot in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way highlight (change color or size) of items in a scatter plot from outside of the chart. I have a table where the rows correspond with items in the chart and on mouse over a row in the table, I want to highlight the items in the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s how to add the events with jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

And:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'pie'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]  ,
        showInLegend: true
    }]
});

// Apply events to text elements (SVG) and spans within the legend (VML + modern browsers with useHTML option).
$('.highcharts-legend text, .highcharts-legend span').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).hover(function() {
        chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].data[index]);
    },function() {
        chart.tooltip.hide();
    })
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/5V33F/).
This is done [programmatically](http://jsfiddle.net/kFg4j/)
And this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/kFg4j/).

Comment: One additional question, is it possible to access the item by an id not by its position in the data array

Comment: In that case instead of using `chart.series[0].data[index]` use [`chart.get('my_id')`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.get).